# Command being marked as invaild

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I just switched to Visual Studio for coding and following a tutorial on Youtube since I'm very new to python. Im trying to add a command to the button in tkinter but it says it is invaild syntax, yet the fellow I am watching does not have an error.
What might I possibly be doing wrong this time?

```py
openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Open File", padx=10, 
                    pady=6, fg="white", bg="black" command = addApp)
```

And that gives me an error of invalid syntax, could it be because my selected shell is Python rather than Bash, as the youtuber is using it or?

This here is the entire piece of code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os


root = tk.Tk()


def addApp():
    filename = filedailog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select File",
    filetypes=(("executables","*.exe"), ("all files,","*.*")))



canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="#263D42")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="black")
frame.place(relwidth = 0.8, relheight= 0.8, relx = 0.1, rely = 0.1)

openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Open File", padx=10, 
                    pady=6, fg="white", bg="black" command = addApp)
openFile.pack()

runApps = tk.Button(root, text="Run Apps", padx=10, 
                    pady=6, fg="white", bg="black")
runApps.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's invalid Python because you forgot the comma separating the `bg` and `command` keyword arguments.

Comment: You appear to be missing a comma after the bg param.

Comment: Typo: filedailog => filedialog

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a comma here:

```
openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Open File", padx=10, 
                    pady=6, fg="white", bg="black" command = addApp)
```

Change to:

```
openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Open File", padx=10, 
                    pady=6, fg="white", bg="black", command=addApp)
```

Comment: Thank you I feel so dumb hahaha!